# Compiling Issues in Porcelli Plsql Parser (ANTLR)

Tags: java, sql, parsing, plsql, antlr

I have downloaded Porcelli Plsql grammar parser from [Porcelli github page](https://github.com/porcelli/plsql-parser). It takes 45 min to compile the plsql project on a system having 512 GB of RAM (Windows 2008 Server) and generate java sources.

Does anyone know why it takes such a long time to compile ANTLR grammar and what happens behind when these grammar files get compiled? Is there any documentation regarding this?

Comment: Have you tried -Xmx10G or something on java?

Comment: Yes I have tried that. It stills take 40 min to compile and generate corresponding java classes. Basically, Porcelli PlSql Parser has 7 grammar files. Out of which only one file (PlSql_DMLParser.g) takes around 40 min to compile, rest gets compile quickly. So, why this one file take such a long time to compile?

Comment: v3 could take a long time on really big grammars. You might ask porcelli how he does it.